# How to rerender component that uses custom React hook

Tags: reactjs

I have a component of localization, kinda like:

```
function useLocalization(localizationConfig: ILocConfig]) {
  const [language, setLanguage] = useState(...);
  const [loc, setLoc] = useState(...);
  const [isLocReady, setLocReady] = useState(...);
  getLoc = useCallback(() => {
    ...
  }, [language, loc, isLocReady]);

  return {getLoc, language, loc, isLocReady}
}
```

And components, which are using this custom hook looks like this:

```
export default function SomeComponent() {
  const {getLoc, isLocReady} = useLocalization(locConfig);

  ...

  return (
    <span>
      {getLoc(localeGroup, localeItemId)}
    </span>
  )
}
```

But! When I change language in this custom hook or change "loc" variable (new localization) - my components aren't rerendering and are using previous localization
Could you help me? What should I do, to rerender every component, that uses this custom hook to get new localization?

Comment: Because you are not using `loc` or `language` in your component. You only get `getLoc` and `isLocReady`?

Comment: I've checked this now
Did {loc, language, getLoc, isLocReady} to some component, but nothing changed - it didn't rerender
Thank you for you answer btw!

Comment: I think I got it now...
But I don't want to use "language", or "loc" in every component! Maybe do you know a way to avoid this, by editing useLocalization hook for example?

Comment: Because "language" and "loc" is "getLoc" method using :\

Comment: If I understood correctly, you want to update loc and language as a global state. Custom hook is not the way to do it. You need something like redux or store them in `localStorage`

Comment: You almost got my idea
I've already done that

But! I don't want to rerender whole page (window.location.reload()) on localization change!

And I want, that all my components, that are using useLocalization() and "getLocItem" in particular, would be re-rendered when I change language (and loc)

getLocItem method looks:
`const getLocItem = useCallback((groupId: string, itemId: string): string => {
        // return value from "loc" variable
    }, [ localization, localizationService ]);`

I dunno, how to re-render these components on loc is change, without reloading the whole page

Comment: `Context` and `Redux` are eligible to do what you just described. And don't ever reload to re-render the component. It is a really bad practice.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly you are trying to modify the loc variable inside the useLocalization hook by calling the getLoc function, the problem is that this is not causing react to update the state inside useLocalization hook to update correctly the loc variable inside the hook you have to use the proper function given by the useState, setLoc. It is best practice to not pass that directly outside of the hook but wrap that around a useCallback like you'r doing with the getLoc.